# how to replace second position string with new in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have one question: in sql server, how to replace the 2nd occurrence of the string `happy` to the string `new`, otherwise keep as it is(same).

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[stringrep](
    [name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [id] [int] NULL
) 
INSERT [dbo].[stringrep] ([name], [id]) VALUES (N'happy happy year', 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[stringrep] ([name], [id]) VALUES (N'very happy new year', 2)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[stringrep] ([name], [id]) VALUES (N'happy new year hello', 3)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[stringrep] ([name], [id]) VALUES (N'happy  happy year', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[stringrep] ([name], [id]) VALUES (N'heloo year happy', 5)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[stringrep] ([name], [id]) VALUES (N'happy happy happy year', 6)
GO
```

based on above data I want output like below:

```
  id  |        Name 
  1   | happy new year
  2   | very happy new year
  3   | happy new year hello
  4   | happy  new year
  5   | heloo year happy
  6   |happy new happy year
```

I tried the query below :

```
SELECT replace ( name  ,'happy happy year' ,'happy new year')afterreplacename,
replace (  name, substring ('happy happy year'  ,6,6) ,' new')anotherway
,name ,[id]
  FROM [test].[dbo].[stringrep]
```

The above query does not give the expected result.

Please tell me how to achive this task in sql server .

Comment: Would the two occurrences of `happy` always been adjacent, or could,  for example, there be a string like `happy New York happy new year` which you would want changed as well?  This will be difficult to swing using SQL Server alone, because it has weak regex support, which is probably the best tool for this job.

Comment: Based only on your example, this should work: `SELECT replace ( name  ,'happy happy' ,'happy new') afterreplacename  FROM [test].[dbo].[stringrep]` (edit: actually almost - there is a double space in one row - so it won't be replaced)

Comment: Create string split function which return two columns rownumber and string column.do this then we proceed further.rownumber because you want to replace even number happy with new.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to come up with the following query.  The replacement logic only targets data having `happy` occurring at least two times.  If so, then we find the index of the second occurrence of `happy`, and then `STUFF` in `new` as a replacement.

```
SELECT
    data,
    CASE WHEN LEN(REPLACE(data, 'happy', '')) < LEN(data) - 6
         THEN STUFF(data,
                    CHARINDEX('happy', data, CHARINDEX('happy', data) + 1),
                     5,
                     'new')
         ELSE data END AS new_data
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that this solution is robust to the two (or more) occurrences of `happy` being anywhere in the string.  See the last row of the sample data for this edge case.

We would rather like to use regex here, and maybe you question could be answered with a one-liner.  But, SQL Server does not have good native regex support, forcing us to use the base string functions instead.

Comment: if you change the second "happy" to "unhappy" the output contains "unnew" for ID=7.

Comment: @MJH I'm not going to update, because to handle your edge case, and whatever else you have in a can of worms, really requires a regex engine, which isn't available here.

Comment: Don't blame you to be honest.  I thought it may be possible to add a space to the front of the string (as a simple solution) but then you get into punctuation and all kinds of different cases (a real can of worms - as you say).

Comment: You'd basically need to add logic to detect word boundaries, which is halfway to writing a primitive regex engine.  It would be better to answer by saying use some UDF.

Answer (score 0):

I find the second occurrence `happy`, if there is only one occurrence `happy` returns the original string, otherwise the string is split. I am get what is before the second occurrence of the word `happy` + `new` + everything that was after the second occurrence of the word `happy`.

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN CHARINDEX('happy', [name], (CHARINDEX('happy', [name])+1)) <> 0 THEN
            SUBSTRING([name],0,CHARINDEX('happy', [name], (CHARINDEX('happy', [name])+1))) 
            + 'new '
            + SUBSTRING([name],CHARINDEX('happy', [name], (CHARINDEX('happy', 
             [name])+1))+5,100)
      ELSE [name]  
   END 
FROM [dbo].[stringrep]
```

Output:

```
happy new  year
very happy new year
happy new year hello
happy  new  year
heloo year happy
happy new  happy year
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be simple RegEx if... SQL Server supports RegExes. I recommend using other tool to replace values - any major programming language with database access and RegEx support. If this is frequent operation, use [CLR Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration-database-objects-user-defined-functions/clr-user-defined-functions?view=sql-server-2017). And then, remember:

> To iterate is human, to recurse divine

This is why:

```
WITH Splitter AS
(
    SELECT id, 1 num, SUBSTRING(name, 1, charindex(' ',name)-1) Word, SUBSTRING(name, charindex(' ',name), LEN(name)) Rest FROM stringrep
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        id,
        num+1 num,
        CASE WHEN charindex(' ',Rest)=1 THEN ' '
             WHEN charindex(' ',Rest)=0 THEN Rest
             ELSE SUBSTRING(Rest, 1, charindex(' ',Rest)-1) END Word,
        CASE WHEN charindex(' ',Rest)=1 THEN SUBSTRING(Rest, 2, LEN(Rest))
             WHEN charindex(' ',Rest)=0 THEN ''
             ELSE SUBSTRING(Rest, charindex(' ',Rest), LEN(Rest)) END Rest
    FROM Splitter
    WHERE LEN(rest)>0
), Replacer AS
(
    SELECT S1.id, S1.num, CASE WHEN LastNotSpace='happy' AND Word='happy' AND (LastLastNotSpace IS NULL OR LastLastNotSpace!='happy') THEN 'new' ELSE Word END NewWord
    FROM Splitter S1
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT id,num,LAG(Word) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY num) LastNotSpace, LAG(Word,2) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY num) LastLastNotSpace FROM Splitter WHERE Word!=' ') T ON S1.id=T.id AND S1.num=T.num
), Joiner AS
(
    SELECT id, num, CAST(NewWord AS nvarchar(MAX)) Joined FROM Replacer WHERE num=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT S.id, S.num, J.Joined+S.NewWord Joined FROM Joiner J
    JOIN Replacer S ON J.id=S.id AND J.num+1=S.num
), Filter AS
(
    SELECT id, Joined FROM (
        SELECT id, num, Joined, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY num DESC) Lev FROM Joiner
    ) T WHERE Lev=1
)
SELECT * FROM Filter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select [name], id, 
       case when secondIndex > 0 then stuff([name], secondIndex, 5, 'new') else [name] end newName
from (
    select [name], id, charindex('happy', [name], charindex('happy', [name]) + 1) secondIndex
    from #stringrep
) a
```